# How to complete the install of KB3105213 - still requires restart after reboot

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

[KB3105213 for Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3105213) came out a few days ago.

There have been a [number of reports](http://news.softpedia.com/news/windows-10-cumulative-update-kb3105213-fails-to-install-for-some-496067.shtml) of it failing to install, but in my case it doesn't fail during the install, rather it - and KB3103688, as you can see from the screenshot, still thinks it needs a reboot for its install to complete:

---

[image: Screenshot of update history]

---

Obviously I've restarted - several times in fact.

I've also downloaded the [manual installer for this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3105213), but it says that it's already installed.

Any suggestions?  Not sure if it's relevant, but the PC usually blue-screens on shutdown for restart; the error it gives is `REFERENCE_BY_POINTER` but I haven't got to the bottom of that one yet.  However, that hasn't seemed to affect previous updates until now.

It's Windows 10 Enterprise, installed clean on new computer; spec [here](http://uk.pcpartpicker.com/p/CsvqZL).

---

**EDIT**:

In case it's relevant, here are the BSOD details:

- BlueScreenView [output](http://5gd.co.uk/bsvreport.html)
- [the .dmp file](http://5gd.co.uk/111515-15718-01.dmp) from the BSOD I alluded to.

---

**EDIT 2**:

Ok, I've removed TrueCrypt (replacing it with VeraCrypt), and the BSOD on restart issue has gone away. My thanks to @magicAndre1981 for that.

However, despite several more reboots (and a graceful shutdown to power-off and restart), Windows updates KB3105213 and KB3103688 are still stubbornly refusing to complete.

Comment: It would help if you gave the BSOD details. [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this. If you can provide a link to the dmp file then@magicandre1981 will probably analyse it for you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that if I looked in the list of uninstallable updates, KB3105213 and KB3103688 were both showing as installed.

So

`Settings > Update and security > Windows Update > Advanced Options`, then

```
View your update history > Uninstall updates
```

I uninstalled them, rebooted, and then did a check for updates - it offered me them again, so I accepted them, and restarted straightaway.

No BSOD, and this time it went through the configuring updates display.  After a second (auto) reboot, the KBs are now showing as complete.

Answer (score 1):

In the dump can see that truecrypt (`\Driver\truecrypt`) is involved.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

REFERENCE_BY_POINTER (18)
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Object type of the object whose reference count is being lowered
Arg2: ffffe001de45b860, Object whose reference count is being lowered
Arg3: 0000000000000006, Reserved
Arg4: ffffffffffffffff, Reserved
    The reference count of an object is illegal for the current state of the object.
    Each time a driver uses a pointer to an object the driver calls a kernel routine
    to increment the reference count of the object. When the driver is done with the
    pointer the driver calls another kernel routine to decrement the reference count.
    Drivers must match calls to the increment and decrement routines. This bugcheck
    can occur because an object's reference count goes to zero while there are still
    open handles to the object, in which case the fourth parameter indicates the number
    of opened handles. It may also occur when the objects reference count drops below zero
    whether or not there are open handles to the object, and in that case the fourth parameter
    contains the actual value of the pointer references count.

Debugging Details:
------------------



               r11 : 0xffffe001dfb7d430 :  !du "\Driver\truecrypt"
0xffffd00028817738 : 0xfffff800fdf0497d : nt!IopDeleteFile+0x1bd
```

The tool is dead and no longer gets updates. Remove it and try to install the update again.

Comment: Thanks for this - as soon as I've found a home for the data in the TC drive I'll uninstall TrueCrypt and try it all again!  Is the tool you used to analyse the dump file freely available?

Comment: yes, this is the program Windbg.exe from the Windows SDK/Debugging Tools: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk